# [Arduino][Register manipulation] How to make your own Serial.print() with registers?

Tags: embedded, arduino-uno, cpu-registers, atmega

(Using VSCode with PlatformIO IDE and Arduino UNO Rev. 3, witch have a ATmega328P microprocessor)

Hi, I started learning about embedded systems' firmware development using register manipulation.
My first goal is to make a "Hello World" program:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.print("Hello world");
```

But directly setting register values to reproduce the same result as the code above.

Following the USART section of ATmega328P, I develop:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

// USART initialization parameters
#define FOSC 8000000 // Clock speed

unsigned int UBRRnAsynchronousNormalMode(int desiredBaud){
  return (FOSC/(16*desiredBaud))-1;
}

void serialBegin(unsigned int UBRRn){
  // Setting baud rate
  UBRR0H = (unsigned char) (UBRRn>>8);
  UBRR0L = (unsigned char) UBRRn;

  // Defining frame format
  UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0) | (3<<UCSZ00);

  // Enabling transmiter
  UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<RXEN0);
}

void serialPrint(unsigned char data){
  while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
  UDR0 = data;
}

void setup() {
  serialBegin(UBRRnAsynchronousNormalMode(9600));
  serialPrint('1');
}
```

The Serial Monitor says "Terminal on COM5 | 9600 8-N-1", but my print results in:

[image]

Sounds like a common baud rate disparity problem, but as I understand, I set my rate to 9600 (same as indicated by the Serial Monitor).
Have I made an error in the code, or missed some step to reproduce a Serial.print()?

Comment: FOSC is 16Mhz and not 8

Comment: Thanks! I saw that ATmega328P's default clock speed was 8MHz, but didn't saw the crystal in the board. Another thing that was wrong is my UBRR calculation FOSC/(16*desireeBaud) result different then FOSC/16/desiredBaud, for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding the numerical limits of types is essential when doing any form of programming, but during old 8 bit MCU programming in particular.

This function is wrong:

```
unsigned int UBRRnAsynchronousNormalMode(int desiredBaud){
  return (FOSC/(16*desiredBaud))-1;
}
```

FOSC is defined as `8000000` and that number, an "integer constant", has a type like everything else. C first tries to see if it can make it type `int`. But since AVR has 16 bit `int`, the largest number is 65535. So instead it tries to fit it inside a 32 bit `long`, which is ok. So the integer constant `8000000` has type `long`.

Meaning that on AVR, your equation is equivalent to `((long)FOSC/(16*desiredBaud))-1`. But here both  `16` and `desiredBaud` are 16 bit `int`. And `16 * 9600` = 153600, so you get an integer overflow.

In comments you describe that `FOSC/16/desiredBaud` fixed the problem. This is because the `/` operators associate operands from left to right, so this is guaranteed to be equivalent to `(FOSC/16)/desiredBaud`. And in the sub expression `FOSC/16`, one operand is `long`. An implicit type promotion happens before calculation (see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/584518)). So it is calculated on `long` and the result is `long` And since the result is `long`, "result"/desiredBaud gets implicitly promoted to `long` too. So it worked by luck... don't rely on luck.

So what to actually do to fix this? Follow best practices:

- (Embedded) systems should never use the "primitive data types" like `int` or `long`. Use the portable types from `stdint.h` instead.
- Embedded systems rarely ever need to use signed numbers. However, signed operands tend to cause a whole lot of problems when combined with bitwise arithmetic, but as noticed they could also overflow in undefined ways. For example `1 << ...` or `1 >> ...` is always dangerous, since `1` is `int` and signed. Always use `1u`.
- Never write programs relying on implicit type promotion. Explicit casts as a means of self-documenting code isn't wrong, neither are extra parenthesis to clear out operator precedence.
- (Avoid 32 bit arithmetic if possible on 8 bit microcontrollers, since it is very slow. Won't work in this specific case though.)

The code could be rewritten as:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define FOSC 8000000ul

uint16_t UBRRnAsynchronousNormalMode (uint32_t desiredBaud){
  return (FOSC / (16ul * desiredBaud)) - 1ul;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already knew that I would have a long way to learn embedded firmware development, but now I see that there is a whole new world to this... and I'm excited to learn it! hahaha Thank you for the advices, specially for the best practices, I'll take it to hearth while studying

Comment: @JoaoV It is much easier to program a 32 bitter than an 8 bitter, because in the former case you don't have to worry so much about implicit promotion and which integer type to pick. So I'd recommend to go with a modern MCU like a Cortex M and not some old 8 bitter.